# Shared function that infers the class type and can be returned in a list

Tags: vb.net

I would like to create a shared function that returns a list of instances of the classes type.  Currently this is what my code looks like

```
class MyClass
    Implements BusinessObject
    Shared Function LoadAll(Of T As {BusinessObject, New})() As IEnumerable(Of T)
            Dim helper = New SQLHelper()
            Return helper.LoadDataTableFromDatabase("LoadTable", LoadAllProcedureName).Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Select(Function(s) New T().FillDataRow(Of T)(s))
    End Function
End Class

class MyDerivedClass Implements MyClass
End MyClass
```

When I go to use it, I have to use it like this:

```
MyDerivedClass.LoadAll(Of MyDerivedClass)()
```

I would like to be able to infer the type, instead of having to use the `(Of MyDerivedClass)` so that my code looks like `MyDerivedClass.LoadAll()`.

Any help or keywords that I am missing to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Type parameter inference requires having method parameters to deduce the type from. Your method has no parameters, so type inference cannot do what you're asking. If you do not need this to be a generic method, you could simply remove `(Of T As {BusinessObject, New})` from the method definition, and explicitly use `MyDerivedClass` instead of `T`. I guess a better question would be, why are you doing this? I would imagine there are better uses of effort than making a line of code more terse.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Code readability and keeping with DRY

Comment: using `MyDerivedClass` will not work because that would require me to repeat the code functionality for every derived class

Comment: If this was Swift I would be able to achieve what I want to do by doing a protocol extension, but I am not aware of how to do this either in VB.net

Comment: I don't see the issue with code readability.  It *looks* sort of like restating yourself, but it really isn't. Remember that the `LoadAll()` method you're calling really isn't part of `MyDerivedClass` and knows *absolutely nothing* about `MyDerivedClass`. There are several ways you can get around having to declare the type. The simplest would probably be to just shadow the LoadAll() method in `MyDerivedClass` - `Shared Function LoadAll() As IEnumerable(Of MyDerivedClass) | Return MyClass.LoadAll(Of MyDerivedClass)() | End Function` - Downside is you have to do this for all derived classes.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot `MyDerivedClass.LoadAll()` reads better than `MyDerivedClass.LoadAll(Of MyDerivedClass)()` (I know I could also do `MyClass.LoadAll(Of MyDerivedClass)()` which I do not like either.) I am trying to keep my code looking as simple as possible.  I have also thought about shadowing, but stopped because of the exact reason you mentioned. It is a shame that the system can't infer this, was hoping it was just me not finding the way to infer it, I guess it is just a limitation of the language.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot, my code was not 100% correct,  MyClass implements BusinessObject

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method which (theoretically) would work on any class you define:

```
Public Module Module1

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function LoadAll(Of T As {BusinessObject, New})(ByVal x As T) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Dim LoadAllProcedureName As String = "LoadAllProcedure"
        Dim helper = New SQLHelper()
        Return helper.LoadDataTableFromDatabase("LoadTable", LoadAllProcedureName).Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Select(Function(s) New T().FillDataRow(Of T)(s))               
    End Function

    Public Sub Main()

        Dim dC As New DerivedClass()
        Dim allDc As IEnumerable(Of DerivedClass) = dC.LoadAll()

        '::: Somewhat shorter syntax
        Dim allDC As IEnumerable(Of DerivedClass) = (New DerivedClass()).LoadAll()

    End Sub

End Module
```

But, as others have pointed out, this doesn't really clean anything up for you. More to the point, you are going to have to type `(Of DerivedClass)` in whatever variable you intend on populating with your enumerated `DerivedClass`, no?

And from what I can tell, you cannot have `Shared` extension methods -- should you be thinking that is the way to go.

Comment: yeah it does stink that VB (or I guess .Net in general) does not allow shared extension methods.  I am also trying to avoid having an instance generate more instances.  The way I am trying to design this, it doesn't "make sense"  Thank you for this though, I am sure others my find it helpful

Comment: Sounds like `BusinessObject.LoadAll(Of DerivedType)()` is where you are going to be stuck...

Comment: Yeah That is most likely what I am going to end up doing in the end.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, if you understand how extension methods work then you know why `Shared` extension methods don't make sense. Extension methods aren't magic. They are simply syntactic sugar. They are just regular methods that take an object as an argument that the compiler allows you to use in code as though you were calling the method on that object. The method itself is already a member of a module so basically already `Shared`. How exactly would an extension method on a type work? The method wouldn't be a member of that type and nor can you pass the type as an argument. Makes no sense.

Comment: @jmcilhinny In Swift you can extend the class to add static methods, which is nice.  Just a limitation of the language, which is why I said it stinks.